# Modifying vtu files that are linked to pvtu files

Tags: vtk, pyvista

I have a bunch of *pvtu files where each of them has ~200 *vtu files linked. I need to do some post-processing where I will be adding and deleting point data for variables. As of now, I do it by reading the files through pyvista and do the post-processing and save them as single *vtu files. Is there a way I can do the saving in *pvtu format so that I can take advantage of the parallel processing?

Comment: PyVista seems to use the [`XMLPUnstructuredGridReader`](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkXMLPUnstructuredGridReader.html#details) VTK class to read parallel vtu files. Since the corresponding [`XMLPUnstructuredGridWriter`](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkXMLPUnstructuredGridWriter.html#details) class is not used anywhere, I would guess this is not something that PyVista directly supports currently.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні Do you think it is a good idea to do the saving part using  ```XMLPUnstructuredGridWriter``` while the rest is done using pyvista in terms of speed? I know it is a hassle to open huge *vtu files compared to *pvtu files, but I believe the visualisations I need can be achieved from pyvista directly too, although I never used it.

Comment: I have no experience with parallel files, not even through PyVista. It's probably not too much work to replicate what existing PyVista readers do under the hood for your specific use case (for a simpler example case if you have more), and you can test if it's worth bothering with. You could also open [a github discussion](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/discussions) to ask feedback from users more experienced myself, or [open an explicit feature request to have this implemented](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/issues/new?assignees=&labels=feature-request&template=feature-request.yml).

Comment: The implementation of `mesh.save()` [is here](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/blob/845b979d8f7322321edb809c9ade33e29ffec6fd/pyvista/core/dataobject.py#L76-L143), it chooses the appropriate writer for the extension (in your case you already know the writer class), sets a few parameters on it and calls `writer.Write()`. Of course you'll have to check what methods are necessary to be called for `XMLPUnstructuredGridWriter`. If you are short on deadlines or just have enough time, I'd try doing this and see how it works.